# syntax in for-loop using local variables

Tags: powershell, for-loop, variables, powershell-remoting

Many of my scripts are using PSsession quite often checking on available shares on several remote PCs. PS-Remoting is great.
Below is the simple working code-snippet:

```
if (Invoke-Command -Session $PSess -ScriptBlock {Get-SMBShare -Name $using:shareName_1 -ea 0}) {
    $mapPS_1=0
    write-Host "available: $shareName_1"
    } else {
    $mapPS_1=1
    write-Host "NOT available: $shareName_1"
    }
```

Instead of repeating this code several times (only with differing variables for the shareNames according to the examples in the list) I would like to create a for-loop (possibly) containing just that code.
Here is a list of shares to be checked upon:

```
$shareName_1='TC-MEDIA-SYSTEM'
$shareName_2='TC-MEDIA-DATA1'
$shareName_3='V-15TB_01'
$shareName_4='W-LL-503DD'
$shareName_5='X-TL-503AA'
$shareName_6='Y-LL-503BB'
$shareName_7='Z-LL-503CC'
$shareName_8='DUMPSTER_01'
$shareName_9='BKUP-NAS-01'
$shareName_10='TC-DUMPSTER_02'
```

As one can read from the code-snippet, depending on the resulting output, one local variable `$mapPS` gets manipulated.

All this works fine as shown above.
The trouble I am facing is to find the **proper syntax for this to run in a for-loop**.

I'd assume that the variable `$using:shareName_$i` is the troubling factor.

This is what I've got so far. Unfortunately, not bearing any fruit.

```
for ($i = 1; $i -lt 11; $i++) {
if (Invoke-Command -Session $PSess -ScriptBlock {Get-SMBShare -Name $using:(Get-Variable -Name shareName_$i).Value} -ea 0) {
    Set-Variable -Name mapPS_$i value 0
    write-Host "available: $shareName_$i"
    } else {
    Set-Variable -Name mapPS_$i value 1
    write-Host "NOT available: $shareName_$i"
    }
}
```

I'm sure Powershell has a solution for this - I just don't know it.
Any hints leading to the solution are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, **consider storing your share names in an *array* instead of in individual variables** (e.g., `$shareNames ='TC-MEDIA-SYSTEM', 'TC-MEDIA-DATA1', ...`), which allows you to reference them by index (e.g., `$shareNames[0]`) instead of having to resort to *variable indirection* via the [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) cmdlet.

---

A simple solution is to create an aux. local variable in the loop that your remote script *can* reference via the [`$using:` scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Remote_Variables#using-local-variables) (which doesn't support commands or expressions):

```
foreach ($i in 1..10) {
  $shareName = Get-Variable -ValueOnly "$shareName_$i"
  if (Invoke-Command -Session $PSess -ScriptBlock { Get-SMBShare -Name $using:shareName } -ea 0) {
    Set-Variable -Name mapPS_$i value 0
    write-Host "available: $shareName_$i"
  }
  else {
    Set-Variable -Name mapPS_$i value 1
    write-Host "NOT available: $shareName_$i"
  }
}
```

Comment: Great, I got it to work as anticipated. The trick was to get the content of `$shareName_$i` into the for-loop ahead of invoking the PSSession.